# Como interpretar mensagens de erro do react Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

Como faço para interpretar mensgans de erro como esta?

Quanto trabalho com react Native ao longo dos testes sempre me deparo com essas mensgans. Só que nem sempre sei tratá-las.

Alguém sabe se tem um padrão que eu posso seguir, alguma matéria que eu posso ver que me ajude a interpretar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendo nada de react (tampouco native), mas tem uns "could not be found" e "Unable to resolve module..." - isso não tem a ver com os `import` que está utilizando? Eles existem?

Comment: Vou verificar aqui, mas acho que não é isso

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0):

Instale o módulo `react-transoform-hmr` com o seguinte comando:

```
npm install react-transform-hmr --save
```

Comment: O que faz este comando ?

Comment: @nathangabriel instala o módulo `react-transform-hmr` que está faltando no seu projeto